# No me convierte en number php

Tags: php

El problema lo tengo que la ultima función, donde intento pasar el numero romano a tipo numero, y de este pasarlo a hexadecimal, que me arroja siempre 5, como si no lo hubiera convertido en numero para la función dechex

```
function romanToDecimalToHex($roman){
    $decimal=(int)romanToDecimal($roman);

   return  dechex ($decimal);
}
echo romanToDecimalToHex('V');
```

**function.php**

```
    <?php
//Pasar de decimal a romano
function decimalToRomano($integer, $upcase = true) 
{
    $table = array('M'=>1000, 'CM'=>900, 'D'=>500, 'CD'=>400, 'C'=>100, 
                   'XC'=>90, 'L'=>50, 'XL'=>40, 'X'=>10, 'IX'=>9,   
                   'V'=>5, 'IV'=>4, 'I'=>1);
    $return = '';
    while($integer > 0) 
    {
        foreach($table as $rom=>$arb) 
        {
            if($integer >= $arb)
            {
                $integer -= $arb;
                $return .= $rom;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $return;
}

//Pasasr de romano a decimal
function romanToDecimal($roman){
    $result = 0;
         $romans = array('M' => 1000,'CM' => 900,'D' => 500,'CD' => 400,
        'C' => 100,'XC' => 90,'L' => 50,'XL' => 40,'X' => 10,'IX' => 9,
        'V' => 5,'IV' => 4,'I' => 1,
    );
    foreach ($romans as $key => $value) {

        while (strpos($roman, $key) === 0) {
            $result += $value;
            $roman = substr($roman, strlen($key));
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
//Pasar de Romano a decimal a hexadecimalQ
function romanToDecimalToHex($roman){
    $decimal=(int)romanToDecimal($roman);

   return  dechex ($decimal);
}
echo romanToDecimalToHex('V');
?>
```

Comment: `V` en romano es `5` en decimal. `5` en decimal es `5` en hexadecimal. ¿Has probado con otros números? Prueba con `X` -> `10` -> `A`.

Comment: tienes razón, y yo dandole vueltas, a ver que pasaba, he probado con X y me arroja a, esta todo bien, siento las molestias, y muchas gracias por su respuesta

Comment: Lo pongo como respuesta y así cerramos la pregunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que solo estás probando con `V`, que es `5` en decimal, y `5` en decimal es `5` en hexadecimal.

Si pruebas con otros números verás que está bien:

```
+--------+-----+-----+
| Romano | Dec | Hex |
+--------+-----+-----+
|   V    |  5  |  5  |
|   X    |  10 |  A  |
| LXVII  |  67 |  43 |
+--------+-----+-----+
```